# Why this javascript onkeypress event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, keyboard-events

This example should fire alert when I add text in the text area, for some reason it does so when I use `$('#sentid1').onkeypress`, and it only works when I use `$('#sentid1').onkeypress`.

html part:

```
<div id="textarea" contenteditable=""><span id="sentid1" class="sentence"> This is sentence 1. </span><span id="sentid2" class="sentence"> This is sentence 2.</span></div>
```

Javascript/jQuery part:

```
 if (1==1) {
  $('#sentid1').onkeypress = function(event) {
            alert("theid: " + this.id);
        };  
  } else{
     document.onkeypress = function(event) {
              alert("theid: " + this.id);
           };   
  }
```

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: I do not see anything related to keypress event there? If this is easy please help, I couldn't make the things word for 3-4 hours both even listener and this.

Comment: Check https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/ on how to work with events (and how to assign event handlers) with jQuery

Comment: I've posted a working answer, containing an explanation why the existing doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you testing that keypress event? In order to trigger keypress event you need your element to be either **focused** or be a parent of some other element on which keypress is triggered, so keypress is **bubbled**.

You're trying to catch keypress on **span**, by default span is not focusable, let's make it with **tabindex** for example

```
<span id="sentid1" class="sentence" tabindex="0"> This is sentence 1. </span>
```

Now you can actually **click** on this span, press some key and see the expected result

Comment: Actually i got, need to add the tabindex everywhwre everywhere.

Comment: If you really want to listen onkeypress event on your span elements rather then on a parent div you should take a look at event delegation concept in js https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: No need for more learning for me today, your solution is perfect, solved the problem I couldn't solve for the last 4-6 hours or so ...

Answer (score 1):

You should attach the event handler like this

```
$(...).keypress(function(event) {...} )
```

or

```
$(...).on('keypress', function(event) {...} )
```

And it needs to be attached to the `#textarea`, since that is the element that can take an input, which the `span` cannot.

```js
$('#textarea').keypress(function(event) {
  alert("theid: " + this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textarea" contenteditable=""><span id="sentid1" class="sentence"> This is sentence 1. </span><span id="sentid2" class="sentence"> This is sentence 2.</span></div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

If to get the `span`, do like this, where you use the `event.target.id` to get which `span`

```js
$('#textarea').keypress(function(event) {
  alert("theid: " + event.target.id);
});
```

```css
#textarea {
  position: relative;
}
span[contenteditable] {
  outline: none;
}
span[contenteditable]:focus::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  outline: 2px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="textarea"><span contenteditable="" id="sentid1" class="sentence"> This is sentence 1. </span><span contenteditable="" id="sentid2" class="sentence"> This is sentence 2.</span></div>
```

Comment: This works but I need to get the id of the element where the key is pressed. So i need to determine in which specific sentence the text is added.

Comment: @Brana Updated with a sample how to get the span

Comment: Actually I use now the solution with adding tabindex="0" ... as this is simpler solution. But this is also awesome solution, Thanks very much,

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
For jquery selector $('#sentid1') use the jquery keypress

```js
if (1==1) {
  $('#sentid1').keypress(function() {
            alert("theid: " + this.id);
        });  
  } else {
     document.keypress(function() {
              alert("theid: " + this.id);
        });   
  }
```

Comment: The `else` part won't be reached and if so would throw an error.

Comment: Even just first part -  $('#sentid1').keypress(function(event) {
            alert("theid: " + this.id);
        });

Comment: then change $('#sentid1') to $('#textarea')

Comment: again - if you want keypress event then you need focus on element

Answer (score 0):

```
if (1==1) {
  $('#sentid1').Keypress(function(event) {
            alert("theid: " + this.id);
        });  
  } else{
     document.Keypress(function(event) {
              alert("theid: " + this.id);
           });   
  }
```

Comment: please  explain what you need help with, no one can help you without knowing the problem you're facing

Answer (score 0):

not clear about your approach if you want a alert writing something on textarea you can use key up

```
if (1==1) {
  $('#sentid1').keyup(function(event) {
            alert("theid: " + this.id);
        });  
  } else{
     document.keyup(function(event) {
              alert("theid: " + this.id);
           });   
  }
```